# Vim randomly renders thing differently

Tags: vim

Suddenly, without any explicit declaration of war my Vim starts to render random files in a very strange way. Actually, this should be colored and sees that weird line numbers.

I've checkout my .vimrc, but it had not changed literally for years. I've uninstalled cscope and pathogen, the only third-party extensions I have, but this steps had not lead me anywhere. 
The most strange thing is that sometimes I get a normal, colorized input and sometimes I don't.

I would really appreciate any hint on this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed an update of your terminal emulator?

If so, have you tried vim with another terminal emulator? Does the problem occur there, too?

Comment: Silly me! Of course this is exactly an issue with terminal emulator!

Comment: @shabunc, could you explain the cause of the issue and how you managed to solve it so that this question helps others.

Comment: @romainl Sure, a friend of mine made a joke while I've been absent for a while. He've set up in my preferences Terminal to behave like VT-100 instead of xterm-256color.

Comment: Funny joke, actually. More subtle than wrapping all your stuff with tin foil.